# Highcharts / Highstock - toggle yaxis from compare to value and back to compare

Tags: highcharts

I want to be able to click a button and toggle y-Axis `plotOptions` from series rendering by absolute value to compare by percent change.

I have played with jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/pn5md4rz/1/

What I have noticed is that if I enable `plotOptions` in the `options` it will render always by change of value or percent change, but if I remove it (commented) it will always render by value. I want a way to switch between both modes of y-axis through button toggle.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add click event callback function to the button and update the chart in that function with variable `compare` and `showInNavigator` values.

```
    document.getElementById('toggle-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
        compare = compare ? false : 'value';
        chart.update({
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    compare: compare
                }
            },
            series: [{}, {
                showInNavigator: !!compare
            }]
        });
    });
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bz3are69/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update